# scala trait or abstract type or parameter type or what?

Tags: oop, scala, traits

I wish to use several classes interchangeably, all of them implementing a method "add", so I start to write a trait:

```
trait CanAdd{
  def add(that: CanAdd): CanAdd
}
```

then implement my classes and hit a problem: I cannot add any "CanAdd" with any other, they need to be of the same class. I workaround the problem with some ugly code relying on "isInstanceOf":

```
class A(val value: Int) extends CanAdd{      
  def add(that: CanAdd): CanAdd = {          
    if(!that.isInstanceOf[A]) sys.error("")  
    val thatA: A = that.asInstanceOf[A]      
    new A(value + thatA.value)               
  }                                          
}                                            
class B(val value: Boolean) extends CanAdd{  
  def add(that: CanAdd): CanAdd = {          
    if(!that.isInstanceOf[B]) sys.error("")  
    val thatB: B = that.asInstanceOf[B]      
    new B(value ^ thatB.value)               
  }                                          
}
```

Finally, I use the classes as follow:

```
class User(val stuff: Array[CanAdd]) {                                            
  def add(that: User): User = {                                                   
    assume(stuff.length==that.stuff.length)                                       
    val out = new Array[CanAdd](stuff.length)                                     
    for( i <- 0 until stuff.length) out(i) = stuff(i).add(that.stuff(i))          
    new User(out)                                                                 
  }                                                                               
}              
val u1=new User(Array(new A(0)))                                           
val u2=new User(Array(new B(false)))                                       
val u3 = u1.add(u1)                                                        
val u4 = u1.add(u2) //should fail, ideally, should not even compile
```

I don't like it because first it is a burden to write the boiler plate code with "isInstanceOf" and second because it fails at run time instead of compile time.

My question: how would you do that, having in mind some plan to implement many more methods than just "add" and maybe to implement few other classes with very different internal representations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
trait CanAdd[T <: CanAdd[T]] { 
  def add(a: T): T 
}

class A(val value:Int) extends CanAdd[A] {
  def add(that:A) = new A(value+that.value)
}

class B(val value:Boolean) extends CanAdd[B] {
  def add(that:B) = new B(value ^ that.value)
}

class User[X <: CanAdd[X] : Manifest](val stuff:Array[X]) extends CanAdd[User[X]]{
  def add(that:User[X]):User[X] = {
    assume(stuff.length==that.stuff.length)
    new User(stuff.zip(that.stuff).map(t => t._1.add(t._2)) toArray)
  }
}

val u1 = new User(Array(new A(0)))
val u2 = new User(Array(new B(false)))
val u3 = u1.add(u1)
val u4 = u1.add(u2)  // compile error: type mismatch
```

Comment: A few explanation probably wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Actually I find it extreme challenge to explain the `trait CanAdd[T <: CanAdd[T]]` things. And the `: Manifest` thing(what is it and why we need it here) deserves a quite long story to tell. Hope someone else can help.

Comment: that does the trick, thanks very much. But yes, the Manifest thing is quiet cryptic to me, google will help I hope...